How to add http://localhost:3000 to Windows through Firewall?
I am following along to a course on Test Automation Academy, on Introduction to Cypress and the course uses:
http://localhost:3000.
Currently I cannot run any the code on my machine I have cloned from GIT as I have Firewall enabled and do not want to turn off all my Firewall for run localhost on my machine, as it would be unsafe.
Does anyone know for Windows, if there is a way to enable a new inbound rule to add http://localhost:3000 to it and to allow an exception for it and how to do it?
A step by step guide to do it and check would be greatly appreciated.
I really appreciate all help given.
Thanks! :)

Are you using system firewall or 3rd party firewall software ?
Also, do you have the required privileges to edit/add firewall rules ?
If you are using Windows Firewall you can access it with Advanced Security console, in your keyboard type Win+R, then type wf.msc, and press ENTER.
Please refer to this link from Microsoft for more information.

Hi Charaf!  I am using Microsoft Windows Defender Firewall for my personal laptop, came with it on purchase!  If you could post step by steps here - simple or any steps, it would be great to configure the post I have mentioned above.  I am a complete beginner at this and this is my first time.

It depends, which one is blocked  by the firewall ? Application ? Port ? Protocol ? .....
